# Magento 2 JS not getting updated in en_CA language view

Tags: magento2, checkout, cache, requirejs

I'm facing the weird issue with JS, in my website we are using `en_CA` as Locale Options where we are generating the static content for `en_CA`. A few days back it works well, but don't know why it is not working now.

When generating the static content the **JS** and **CSS** are generating well and we are able to see them under the `pub/themefolder/`..

But, when we are browsing the website we are unable to see the changes made in the JS. We even removed the complete code from the JS in pub folder but even then we are unable to see the change in the frontend.

We have tried in private browser, removing the cache from the browser stil the JS modifications are not getting reflected in the frontend.

I have run the following commands, the current mode setting is the **default**.

```
setup upgrade
static content
compilation
cache flush
indexing
```

Also, there is no JS,CSS merging set.

Is any body faced this type of weird issues in Magento2? please share valuable your inputs or suggestions to narrow down the issue.

PS: We are using redis and Varnish cache.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please tell us exact JS path ?

Comment: We are using the custom module, where we have added our own JS file, which is been loading well until today. Also, I see that it is getting reflected in the en_US locale folder.

Comment: I ran into this before and the solution was to run  "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_CA" - it seems the deploy command only deploys en_US in some cases. May help - may not, but worth a shot.

Comment: @dawhoo: I'm have tried generating the static content individually for en_CA, as the static content deploy with out any language will generate for only en_US. But, no luck facing issues.

Comment: Updated my question regarding the caching used in website.

Comment: @ImranSheik you got any solution for this issue?